# Antialiased text in image using cacheDisplayInRect

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, nsview

I'm able to create an image of a view using the code below, but the text in the image is not antialiased.

```
NSRect visRect = [self bounds];
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapImageRep = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:visRect];
bzero([bitmapImageRep bitmapData], [bitmapImageRep bytesPerRow] * [bitmapImageRep pixelsHigh]);
[self cacheDisplayInRect:visRect toBitmapImageRep:bitmapImageRep];
```

I suspect the reason for this is related to the difficulty of rendering antialiased text in a layer-backed view, but I'm wondering if there is a way of solving this specific problem.

Comment: Im having a somewhat similar issue, using the above code, the resulting image is ignoring the alpha and shadow properties of all the subviews in the view i am capturing